# .env.local variables not being accessed (undefined) in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, environment-variables, .env

I am trying to access my environment variables in my application made with Next.js.

From the Next.js docs. I need to put the environment variables in a `.env.local` file and access them with `process.env.<ENV_VARIABLE>`. I have done all this, but it is still returning `undefined`.

**Relevant file paths:**

root/.env.local

root/db/index.ts

**.env.local:**

```
ENV_VAR=test
NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR=publicTest
```

**db/index.ts:**

```
console.log(process.env.ENV_VAR)
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR)
```

In every thread I've come across on Stack Overflow so far the accepted answer is to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` for the environment variable, but this had no effect. The index.ts file returns `undefined` for both variables.

From another thread I have added `reactStrictMode: true` to nextConfig in next.config.cjs, but that also had no effect.

I had dotenv installed, but after looking at aanother thread and one on GitHub, I uninstalled dotenv twice, once with `npm uninstall dotenv` and again with `npm r dotenv`. These commands also had no effect.

I use `ts-node --esm db/index.ts` to run the index.ts file.

Comment: Running the file directly does not make use of any of the Next.js framework so there will be no `.env` file parsing. Why are you trying to run the file directly with `ts-node` anyway?

Comment: @Phil Thanks, Phil. I was just trying to make set up my back end with my database and wanted to check if what I had there worked. The strings themselves worked, but the environment variables didn't so it had me worried about production. But I will continue setting up the back end and cross that bridge when I come to it.